# Who would be the survivors after end of Kali Yuga?

Tags: yuga, kali-yuga

What do the scriptures say about would be the survivors after end of Kali Yuga?

Comment: There are immortals like Hanuman who will survive the Kali yuga.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu Which scriptures mention about immortal beings on earth in kaliyug?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Puranas, the devotees of God will survive at the end of kaliyuga.

Brahma-Vaivarta-purana says

> brahmandani viinashyanti deva indraadayastatha/Kalyaanabhaktiyuktascha madbhakto na pranashyati, meaning that **when the worlds and the devas like Indra are desroyed [during pralaya]], my devotees wih good qualities are not desroyed.** Ref. Omkarnath Rachanavali, vol 6,page 28).

The Saura-Purana says

> jagatah prlaye praapte nashte cha kamalodbhave/madbhaktaah naiva nashyanti sveachchavigrahadhaarnaha, meaning **at the time of pralaya when even Brahma can not survive, my devotees taking the forms according to their wish always survive**(Ibid page 33).